# Can I create an RDD from a kafka topic if I do not know the until offset?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

[KafkaUtils.createRDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka/KafkaUtils.html#createRDD(org.apache.spark.SparkContext,%20scala.collection.immutable.Map,%20org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.OffsetRange[],%20scala.reflect.ClassTag,%20scala.reflect.ClassTag,%20scala.reflect.ClassTag,%20scala.reflect.ClassTag)) takes the offsetRanges as a parameter. I do not know the until offset of the topic I want to read from. I want to read at most the first 30 messages in the topic.

I see there is a [KafkaCluster.html#getLatestLeaderOffsets](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka/KafkaCluster.html#getLatestLeaderOffsets(scala.collection.immutable.Set)) but that is annotated as a Develop API.

Is there any public way to determine the earliest and latest offsets for a topic?

Answer (score 3):

It's not that simple of a thing, because only the individual brokers know what the latest offset info for a given topic / partition is.

You can do an `OffsetRequest`. The following will return the earliest and latest offsets for a topic / partition (it's Scala, but you should be able to get the idea if you don't use Scala).

Note you have to use a `SimpleConsumer` connected to the broker that is the leader for the requested partition. Usually what I do is, I create a `SimpleConsumer` for each of my brokers. Then I do a meta data request and get the partition to leader mapping, then foreach partition I do this:

```
def getOffsets(consumer: SimpleConsumer, topic: String, partition: Int) : (Long,Long) = {
  val time = kafka.api.OffsetRequest.LatestTime
  val reqInfo = Map[TopicAndPartition,PartitionOffsetRequestInfo]((new TopicAndPartition(topic, partition)) -> (new PartitionOffsetRequestInfo(time, 1000)))
  val req = new kafka.javaapi.OffsetRequest(reqInfo, kafka.api.OffsetRequest.CurrentVersion, "offReq")
  val resp = consumer.getOffsetsBefore(req)
  val offsets = resp.offsets(topic, partition)
  if (offsets.size > 0) (offsets(offsets.size - 1), offsets(0))
  else (0, -1)
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: great job @David, do you have a complete example of this? 
And.. why are you using `kafka.javaapi.OffsetRequest` if there is the Scala object with the same name ?