# stop spark Streaming context kafkaDirectStream

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I want to end the stream processing after receiving and processing is complete from kafka topic. The stop should no be time specific like ( awaitTerminationOrTimeout ). Is there a way to stop the sparkstreamingcontext after the topic exhausts. is there a way for the Dstream[T] to be compared with T values to dictate the control flow?

Answer (score 0):

I'm about 80% cetain that `isEmpty` should return true and `headOption` should be None on `KafkaMessageStream` if the stream is empty.

Comment: rdd.isEmpty  of kafkaStream.foreachRDD does return true. But it doesn't stop the application with sparkStreamingContext.stop(true)

Comment: You could do something like:

`Future({() => while(!kafkaMessageStream.isEmpty) { 
      Thread.sleep(100)} sparkTreamingContext.stop(true)
    })`

This will check every 100 ms to see if there are any messages and will stop if there are none.

Comment: You can get false positives, for example if the broker goes wonky for a period longer than your batch interval.

Comment: I started using sys.exit() rather than sparkStreamingContext.stop() as the latter doesn't stop the application in driver.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is, before you start reading the stream, get the latest offsets for all of the partitions in the topic and then check when the received offsets have gotten there. If you want to find out how to get the offsets of a topic, see my **[previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36970140/4856939)** on this.

The flow ends up being:

1. Get the partitions and brokers for the topic
2. For each broker, create a `SimpleConsumer`
3. For each partition, do an `OffsetRequest` where you return the
   earliest and latest offsets (see previous answer)
4. Then as you read messages, check the offset of the received message
   relative to the know last offset for the partition
5. Once all the offsets received for each partition are the same as the
   latest receieved in your `OffsetRequest` you are done