# Kafka 9 (Java API) get message at x Offset

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am trying to implement an event queue in Kafka but clients need the ability to replay events starting from a specific event number.  I can set an "offset" in Kafka but what does that really mean across partitions?  If a client asks to start at event # 12, setting the offset to 12 for all partitions doesn't make much sense.  Is the only way to do this by using a single partition per topic?  If so, what's the performance hit for that (anyone have benchmarks for different partition numbers)?

Comment: What's your partitioning scheme?

Comment: You could, for example, partition on the modulus of the event #. If you have 4 partitions, event 0 would be in partition 0, event 1 in partition 1, event 2 in partition 2, event 3 in partition 3, event 4 back in partition 0, etc. Then if someone wanted to replay from a specific point, you know exactly where to start in which partitions. That being said -- the events are going to come in out of order -- you can't maintain ordering except within a single partition.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that - but unfortunately we don't actually have an event # on the way in so the service would have to have some sort of distributed counter to keep track.  Still thinking....

Comment: Timestamp? The Kafka `OffsetRequest` APIs let you specify a UNIX timestamp so you can get the offsets since then. The other possibility is to write a confirmation back into the same partition -- so request and response are in the same partition. Then, when a consumer starts up, it can blow through the topic (from a past point in time perhaps) and find all requests without corresponding responses.

Comment: Hmm, that's not in the regular Java API docs - any examples of how this is done?

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36970140/4856939